# How to know which jar to add for a specific java class, and how to add it in maven

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I guess I'm new to maven,

Say I want to use a specific class which I found from the docs, (Or, as in this case, I had a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`). For example ["StreamCapabilities"](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/class-use/StreamCapabilities.html)

How, from the javadoc, do I know which jar I need to add to my dependencies?
I know the package is `org.apache.hadoop.fs`, but which jar contains this?

Also, suppose I know which jar I need, how do I know what to write in maven `groupID` and `artifactID`?

Comment: There's no precise way to do that. The best is to get setup instructions from the same site that gives the API docs. One way to get to the jars is searching artifacts on search.maven.org by class name.

Comment: There is no general rule, you need to check the documentation of the library you use, and if they don't document it, then it becomes trial and error.

Comment: If you know the jar you can search for it on maven central

Comment: Thanks... It's weird that there's no precise link from the javadoc to the jar name. Is there a way in the case of apache classes? Like the one I mentioned, for example.

Comment: In **general** googling something like: *org.apache.hadoop.fs.StreamCapabilities Maven* will give you a link to the correct Artifact. Here e.g. it links to Hadoop Core which is probably what you need. It's a good first quick thing to start at least. Other than that it's really just... well knowing where it's to be found or doing a bit of trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way for adding maven dependency, you can refer mvnrepository.com for this :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.20.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Googling the class results in the maven site which lists the jar that contains the class.
We cannot get the information of the jar unless the doc publisher has included it in the doc. As for your last question what groupId/artifactId need to added to the POM file can be found from [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/) once you know which jar is to be added, for this we need to search maven repository for the specific jar.